# Kotlin Unable to reset variable

Tags: kotlin

```
class Sokoban(Playground: Array<CharArray>)  
{    
    private var playground = Playground    
    private val _Playground = Playground    
    fun move(d: String) {    
        ...//"playground" got modified.         
    }    
    fun restart() {
        playground = _Playground
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {    
    val Playground: Array<CharArray> = arrayOf(    
            "###########".toCharArray(),    
            "#$...*....#".toCharArray(),    
            "#..@......#".toCharArray(),    
            "###########".toCharArray()    
    )    
    val sokoban = Sokoban(Playground.clone()) 
    sokoban.move("Left")
    sokoban.restart()   
    }
```

The code above was expected to reset the variable "playground" when function "restart" is called,yet it fails.Instead variable "_Playground" is modified.
How to fix this abnormal problem?

Comment: To begin with, this code doesn't even compile. Second, the variable `_Playground` certainly isn't modified as it's a `val`, you probably mean that the _object_ it refers to is modified. And that, of course, is the expected consequence of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This code can't work as you expect because Java, and, consequently, Kotlin use references, not objects. So your variable `_Playground` is just a reference to your variable `playground`. If you want it to work as you expect — make `_Playground` a cloune of `Playground` variable.

Also your code won't compile because you do not pass `Playground` as field and your `reset` method have no access to it.

---

I think that you should know that you do not follow style guides of java/kotlin. Generally variables should be named in camelcase and start from lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks for answering.But...It did compline successfully, and using a clone seemingly…doesn't work.

Comment: class Sokoban(Playground: Array<CharArray>) { private var playground = Playground private val _Playground = Playground fun move(d: String) { ...//"playground" got modified. } fun restart() { playground = _Playground } } fun main(args: Array<String>) { val Playground: Array<CharArray> = arrayOf( "###########".toCharArray(), "#$...*....#".toCharArray(), "#..@......#".toCharArray(), "###########".toCharArray() ) val sokoban = Sokoban(Playground.clone()) sokoban.move("Left") sokoban.restart() }

Comment: @Dzx your Playground variables is still not field

Comment: @Dzx is stil not field of `Sokoban` class. `_Playground` is still not a clone of `Playground`

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your code isn't following coding conventions and has references, and other issues. But learning a new language isn't always easy. Here's a solution that works (with an added print() to show the results and allow me to confirm the result ;)

I defined 'move' to set the first element to the string passed.

This creates Sokoban with a modifiable, private property called playground. Must be modifiable (var) so that it can be restarted.

The internal property _playground takes a clone so it can be restored later.

Also tidied up names of items. Hope this helps on your journey of learning Kotlin.

```
class Sokoban(private var playground: Array<CharArray>) {
    private val _playground = playground.clone()
    fun move(d: String) {
        playground[0] = d.toCharArray()
    }

    fun restart() {
        playground = _playground
    }

    fun print() {
        println("Current value")
        playground.forEach { println(it) }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val playground: Array<CharArray> = arrayOf(
        "###########".toCharArray(),
        "#$...*....#".toCharArray(),
        "#..@......#".toCharArray(),
        "###########".toCharArray()
    )
    val sokoban = Sokoban(playground)
    sokoban.move("Left")
    sokoban.print()
    sokoban.restart()
    sokoban.print()
}
```

Comment: It seemingly doesn't work fine when one character of playground is modified.

Comment: If I replace 
playground[0] = d.toCharArray()
with 
playground[0][0] = '@'
, it wouldn't be reset.